# How to create custom MSTest Assert-methods with "proper" callstack

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, assert

I'm writing extension methods for testing values for my unit-test. A naïve example would be:

```
public static void ShouldBeTrue(this bool value)
{
    if(!value)
    {
        throw new AssertFailedException("Expected true");
    }
}
```

And using it in a test:

```
someBool.ShouldBeTrue();
```

Everything works, except that the line throwing the exception will be the one I end up on when double-clicking the failed test in the Test Results window, and in Test Result Details the throw-line is shown in the Error Stack Trace.

Is there a way round this, so that "someBool.ShouldBeTrue();":

1. is the line that double-clicking the failing test in Test Results window opens?
2. is the only line in stack trace?

Comment: If you're doing this, you might take a look at this project: http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/.

Comment: A quick but dirty solution would be to name the namespace of your extension method class `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`. Methods from this particular namespace will be removed from the stack trace by the MSTest test runner. This is a hack, though; not a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer.  All you need to do is put your custom assertion classes/methods into a seperate assembly.  You can have this as a seperate project in the same solution, if you like.

Comment: Could have sworn that I had my custom assertion methods in a separate assembly when I wrote this question. However, when I try now, everything works as expected. My test projects references a dll containing the assertion methods and when a test fails 1 (in my original question) is fulfilled. 2 is not, but that's ok. 
Thanks

Comment: Make sure there's no .pdb file for the separate assembly.

Comment: So is there no way to satisfy the second option here?  The MS Test framework is somehow managing to do it...

Answer (score 2):

There's a class library already written for that: http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/01/31/adding-custom-assertions-to-mstest.aspx

There's a quote from the link above:

> ... For reference, those unavailable Asserts are:
>
> - Assert.IsNaN
> - Assert.IsEmpty
> - Assert.IsNotEmpty
> - Assert.Greater
> - Assert.GreaterOrEqual
> - Assert.Less
> - Assert.LessOrEqual
> - Assert.IsAssignableFrom
> - Assert.IsNotAssignableFrom
> - CollectionAssert.IsEmpty
> - CollectionAssert.IsNotEmpty
> - StringAssert.AreEqualIgnoringCase
> - StringAssert.IsMatch
> - FileAssert.AreEqual
> - FileAssert.AreNotEqual
>
> ...I have created a class library that includes all of them except the FileAssert methods and StringAssert.IsMatch. ... You can download the class from my SkyDrive public folder: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=93d618d639ec9651&id=93D618D639EC9651%211283